# C# Get Value of a text box in a Static Void

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to get the value of a text box called txtNum on the form FrmPhone as well as write to the text box txtLog however there seems to be no interacation between the Static Void and the Text Boxes on FrmPhone.

Below is the code for the CreateCall Static Void.

```
    private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCall();
    }

    static void CreateCall()
    {
        FrmPhone FrmPhone = new FrmPhone();
        var numberToDial = FrmPhone.txtNum.Text;
        FrmPhone.txtLog.Text += "\r\nCall " + numberToDial;
        FrmPhone.txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
        SetupDevices();
        call = softphone.CreateCallObject(phoneLine, numberToDial);
        call.CallStateChanged += call_CallStateChanged;
        call.Start();
    }
```

What am I missing to allow me to interact with the text boxes on the form while executing code in the static void?

Also worth noting is that If replace

```
var numberToDial = FrmPhone.txtNum.Text;
```

with

```
var numberToDial = "2788";
```

The call is made but the txtLog text does not change.

Comment: But your creating a new form, `FrmPhone FrmPhone = new FrmPhone();` this won't be the form your trying to interact with..it's a new one!

Comment: Seems the solution is to just remove `static` and interact with the form instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

1. You make the method non-static. This is the easiest solution and the one that makes most sense. You are after all using instance variables.

   ```
   void CreateCall()
   {
       var numberToDial = this.txtNum.Text;
   }
   ```
2. Pass in the form to the method, as said, it doesn't make sense, but it does the job. `txtNum` needs to be `internal` or `public`, or `CreateCall` must reside in the same class:

   ```
   static void CreateCall(FrmPhone frmPhone)
   {
       var numberToDial = frmPhone.txtNum.Text;
   }
   ```

   In calling the code you pass in `this`:

   ```
   CreateCall(this);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Converting the "Static Void" to "Void" was the most effective way.